# Eclipse color theme works for text editor only

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The color theme in my Eclipse installation somehow works for the text editor only, not everything.  It can be seen below.  Really appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance_, did you set _Theme_ to _Dark_? Which Eclipse version do you use? (It looks like you are using a very old version and didn't restart Eclipse.)

Comment: I am using the latest version, 3.8 on Ubuntu with C++.

Comment: Got it.  3.8 is the latest version thru terminal download.  The latest one is 4.7 installed thery.  Thru their tar.gz file from the website.  This solves the mystery.  Thank @howlger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a **very old version of Eclipse** and **switched to the *Dark* theme without restarting** Eclipse.

Especially when using the *Dark* theme, make sure to **use the latest version of Eclipse**: currently, Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)

(For example, see [*Dark* theme improvement of Oxygen.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8&feature=youtu.be&t=7m45s))

Comment: Yea as commented above, the terminal installation got me that v.3.8.  I am new to Linux and didnt know it was not maintained.  Fixed it, and it worked.